# How to get the cursor position and write on that position in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to write some data on the cursor position of the system through C# programming.

I get the cursor position by `Cursor.position` but cannot write on that position.

Comment: Do you want to write to a `control` at the cursor's location?

Comment: what is "some data"? what do you want to write? are you using winforms or wpf or what?

Comment: I think he wants to move the mouse cursor programatically. With the question in its current state we can only guess what his intentions are...

Comment: Its a window application, suppose there is textbox and button and whatever i write in textbox it sholud be go to the cursor position wherever it is on the system.

Comment: @Shraddha Seriously, if you want to get help, you should spend some time trying to ask a question properly. Acting lazy and sloppy while expecting people to spend their time to help you is disrespectful.

Answer (score 4):

Hard to guess at the real intention for this question.  But here's a simple Winforms form class that does what you ask:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BackColor = this.TransparencyKey = Color.Fuchsia;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        var timer = new Timer() { Interval = 50, Enabled = true };
        timer.Tick += delegate {
            this.Location = Cursor.Position;
            // this.Invalidate();   // Uncomment if the text should change
        };
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
        e.Graphics.DrawString("hello world", this.Font, Brushes.Black, 10, 0);
    }
}
```

Finding a way to terminate the program is a //todo item.